# Update all a field in all document based on another field in that document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have student documents in my database. Each document is a student and has the fields `amountOwed` and `tuition`.

I am trying to **update** the `amountOwed` to be equal to the current value of `amountOwed + tuition.`

I've thought about using a **`.find`** query to get all the student documents, looping through each document and updating the database.

I've also researched and found the **`$set(aggregation)`** and **`$addFields(aggregation)`** in the mongo documentation but I'm not sure if I can use that for what I'm trying to do.

**Example documents:**

```
{"studentName" : "Student1",

 "amountOwed" : 100,

 "tuition" : 100

},

{"studentName" : "Student2",

 "amountOwed" : 0,

 "tuition" : 500

}
```

**Output** should be:

```
{"studentName" : "Student1",

 "amountOwed" : 200,

 "tuition" : 100

},

{"studentName" : "Student2",

 "amountOwed" : 500,

 "tuition" : 500

}
```

Is there any way to do this all within one database query?

Maybe using a `updateMany`?

Comment: what is the mongo version you are using? $set (aggregation) is supported in mongo version 4.2+.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To add values you can use [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) expression of Mongo Aggregation Query.

Try using the query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      studentName: 1,
      tuition: 1,
      _id: 0,
      amountOwed: {
        $add: [
          "$amountOwed",
          "$tuition"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: He doesn't want to query the collection, he wants to update all the docs. Please read the question.

Comment: so just add an {$out :"collection"} stage at the end of aggregation query.